# for which real values of $a$ the limit is finite and different from $0$ $\lim_{ x \to 0 } \frac{ \cos (\pi \cdot \frac{1-\cos ax}{x^2})}{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have to find for which real values of $a$ this limit is finite and different from $0$:
$$\lim_{ x \to 0 }  \frac{ \cos (\pi \frac{1-\cos ax}{x^2})}{x^2}$$

I've tried to change the form of cos but with no success.
According to my book the final result should be for $a^2=2k+1 (k \in N)$ for which $\lim=\frac{(-1)^k (2k+1)^2 \pi}{24}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos ax}{x^2}= a^2\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos ax}{(ax)^2}=\frac{a^2}{2}$$

Comment: This comes from $\cos x\approx 1-\frac{x^{2}}{2}$.

Comment: This comes from L' Hospital rule also.

Comment: And more simply it is a standard limit.

Comment: @Abigubude It needn't:$$\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{2\sin^2(x/2)}{x^2}=\frac12\operatorname{sinc}^2\frac{x}{2}\stackrel{x\to0}{\to}\frac12.$$

Comment: but if I put $a^2=1+2k$ the limit is zero and we don't want this

Comment: There is an error in your question. The limit is zero if $a^2= 2k+1$ and non zero otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

We start from

$$\cos(ax)=1-\frac{a^2x^2}{2}+\frac{a^4x^4}{4!}(1+\epsilon(x))$$

to get

$$\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x^2}=\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{a^4x^2}{24}(1+\epsilon(x))$$

If The limit is finite, then necessarily

$$\cos(\pi.\frac{a^2}{2})=0$$

or

$$a^2=1+2k , k\ge 0$$

In this case

$$A=\pi(\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{a^4x^2}{24}(1+\epsilon(x))=$$
$$\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi-\frac{a^4x^2\pi}{24}(1+\epsilon(x))$$

and

$$\cos(A)=-(-1)^k\sin(\frac{a^4x^2\pi}{24}(1+\epsilon(x)($$

$$\sim -(-1)^k\frac{a^2x^2\pi}{24}$$

the limit will be
$$-(-1)^k\frac{a^4\pi}{24}=-(-1)^k\frac{(1+2k)^2\pi}{24}$$